# Can't share from any apps, no links or files (action.CHOOSER ActivityNotFoundException)

Tags: custom-roms, share-menu, intents, android-14

On Android 14 GrapheneOS, I am unable to share images or links in multiple applications (such as Mull, Aves Gallery, YouTube, NewPipe, Twitter, and many others). Some apps crash, others do nothing when you press "more" to show more apps, and others say "Cannot open this link" or "No app on your device can open this link"

When I go to logcat or see the crash log when offered, every application shows this error

```
E AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER (has extras) }
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue, since it only started happening very recently. It's possible that in my clouded judgement, I messed with some app permissions to prevent an app from updating itself, but my attempts to revert the permissions had been fruitless and I don't know if it could have been anything else. Any help would be appreciated.

I tried looking online, and every answer assumes the problem is on the application's end and that you are the developer. I couldn't find anything here or Super User, only Stack Overflow.

Comment: someone posted an answer as an edit, instead of posting it as an answer or a comment. I think there was a misunderstanding, it should be stated that this happens with every app on the mobile device.

I will update if I find the problematic system application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions are here

https://www.reddit.com/r/android_beta/comments/146v09p/comment/jnu3bdk/
https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/1914

```
$ adb root
$ adb shell pm enable com.android.intentresolver/.ChooserActivity
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Sad to see a factory reset is my only choice as someone not using root. I was thinking of doing that recently. Thanks a lot for the answer